# Prove that $F = \{\,a^i b^j\mid i = kj \text{ for some positive integer }k\ \}$ is not context free

Tags: automata, context-free-grammar

This question is borrowed from sipser 2nd ed.

Show that  $F = \{\,a^i b^j\mid i = kj \text{ for some positive integer }k\ \}$ is not context free.

I tried it but did not get any clue about the scenario ; which shall oppose it being context free.

Let pumping length is  $p$ and suppose we take string $a^{2p} b^p$ for pumping lemma test.

If we take $a^p$ as pumping portion then it'll always be in the language.

$a^i b^j$ | $i = kj$

Please provide me the scenario which shall work out.

Help appreciated :)

Comment: When you use the [pumping lemma for context free languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_context-free_languages), the pumping portion is actually two portions, possible split by intervening material; it sounds as if you’re thinking of the [pumping lemma for regular languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages).

Comment: Yes sir, I do know that.  Here I assumed one part is empty (which is permissible ), as  the basic rule says at least one between two must be non empty.

Comment: And since you’re showing that there are decompositions that can’t be pumped out of $F$, you’ve shown that your word doesn’t work. Good. I wasn’t sure whether you were doing that, or whether you were using the wrong pumping lemma, as Hagen seems to have done.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Try to pump $a^{p+1}b^{p+1}$

Comment: Banging head after seeing the hint ..thanks a lot :)

Comment: That works easily to show that the language isn’t regular; it doesn’t work to show that the language is not context free, since you might end up decomposing that word as $uvwxy$ with $u=a^p$, $v=a$, $w=\lambda$, $x=b$, and $y=b^p$. In that case pumping always gives you a word of the form $a^nb^n$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott This is true. Then do you have any other string which we can pump up/down to show that it does not satisfy pumping lemma. or For every string this satisfies pumping property but can not be a CFL ( as satisfying pumping does not lead to guarantee that its in the same language)

Comment: @ViX28: I’ve not thought this out in detail, but $a^{(p+1)^2}b^{p+1}$ looks like a good candidate — worth investigating, at least.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I kind of getting the feeling that you nailed it . Let me check too.